# PHP display database using a search result

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to create a search menu, and display it's result in a form of table. I managed to get the search result only as a string, but unable to use it to display a full row in the table. 
Here is my code :
- Creating the Form :

```
<form action = "profile.php" method = "post">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder = "Search">
            <input type="submit" value = "SEARCH"><br>
        </form>
```

This is the php to get search result

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
        {
            $searchq = $_POST['search']; 
            $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM identity WHERE fullname LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not Find!");
            $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

            if($count == 0)
            {
                $output = 'There is no result';
            }
            else
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                    $fullname =  $row['fullname'];
                    $output .= '<div> '.$fullname.' </div>';
                    $records = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM identitas_pengadu WHERE fullname='$output'");
                }

            }           
        }
```

This is the code I used to display the result in a database :

```
while($identity = mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
                {           
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$identity['fullname']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$identity['nip']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$identity['email']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$identity['position']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$identity['status']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href=\"profiledetails.php?nip=".$identity['nip']."\">EDIT</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

It works fine if the value of $records does not use the WHERE function. Please help.
Thank You

Comment: you use $identity, $identitay, and $identitas_pengadu in the same block, is it right?

Comment: You seem to look for a value in the identitas_pengadu column in the database that consists of accumulating (".=") combinations of '<div>' + fullname + '</div>'. That seems a bit fishy.

Comment: the $identity is indeed in a same block.
actualy I'm trying to use the fullname column in identity database, to view a full database row

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I wanted display table based on the search result, the parameter I'm using is fullname column in the identity table